# How to use JqueryAutocomplete sending more than one parameter on the request

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm developing an API that will return JSON, but the API call have two parameters, "term" and "country":

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/internalapi/cidades/?country=PT&term=Barreir
```

How can I modify this call to support the extra API parameter "country"?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/internalapi/cidades/",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any clues?

Best regards,

---

Update 1:

The HTML for choosing the country:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="id_country">País:</label>
    <select id="id_country" name="country">
        <option selected="selected" value="">(Nothing)</option>
        <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
        <option value="ES">Espanha</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the parameter into the data object:

```
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term,
                country: $('#id_country').find(":selected").val()
            },
```

Comment: Hi freedev. It is possible to the country to be dynamic? I have requests like "?country=ES&term=Madr", "?country=UK&term=Lond" and so on.

Comment: Yes, but in your post I have no clues to understand where the country parameter came from. If you specify the piece of html where the country is, or the piece of javascript that read such value I could help you

Comment: I've build the API but not the HTML. I will get the country from a drop-down box right before of choosing the city. Is this the best way of doing it? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Please add into your post the HTML  containing the form, or at least the element used for the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks freedev. I've made an update in the original question. How can I get the value of the drop-down box directly to the request? Best Regards,

Comment: $('#countryDropdown').find(":selected").val()
But you must add to select element an id, to uniquely identify it.
Something like id="countryDropdown"

Comment: Sorry, I miss the select id is already set to id_country . I have updated the answer